# C# Multithreading Video Record feed

Tags: c#, multithreading, video-capture, aforge

I had this doubt regarding a multithreading approach to record a video from my webcam. I am using [AForge](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/) framework.

The code runs fine and the video gets saved too if on a single thread. But, while recording is in progress the stream freezes. I think using a different thread for the recording should do the trick.

I have this function which is recording a clip of about 4 sec:

```
void startrecord()
    {
        writer.Codec = "wmv3";
        writer.FrameRate = 30;
        writer.Open("C://temp//test.avi", pictureBox1.Image.Width, pictureBox1.Image.Height);

        // create frame image
        Bitmap image = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image.Width, pictureBox1.Image.Height);

        for (int i = 0; i < 240; i++)
        {
            image = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;

            //Add Date Time Stamp
            RectangleF rectf = new RectangleF(10, 10, 140, 17);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image);              //00
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, rectf);
            g.DrawString(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd:MM:yyyy HH:mm:ss"), new Font("Tahoma", 10), Brushes.Red, rectf);
            g.Flush();

            writer.AddFrame(image);
        }
        writer.Close();
    }
```

The above function is invoked by the button click event:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //1: Thread t2 = new Thread(startrecord);
        //2: t2.Start();
        startrecord();   //3
    }
```

Now, when I try to run lines 1 and 2, I get the error

> Object is currently in use elsewhere.

With the JIT pointing to the line marked //00 .

P.S. I am very new to C# coding, and tried 'lock' , but I wasn't able to implement that properly.

Any help would be appreciated very much. Thanks!

Comment: OK, just to back up a bit.. does your webcam interface fire any event or otherwise signal that it has just completed rendering a complete frame to the PictureBox?  Iask because that is the time to snaphot the image and queue it off for processing/saving in another thread.

Comment: @Martin

Yes, it does. The new frame event handler is : 
'FinalVideo.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalVideo_NewFrame);'

and the function is:

void FinalVideo_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            //Frame Handler
            Bitmap video = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
            pictureBox1.Image = video;
        
        }

Comment: and where is the "writer" object initialised, I think it should be initialised in the startRecord function itself.

Answer (score 0):

GDI+ objects are not thread-safe. I would recommend to try something like that:

```
writer.AddFrame((Bitmap)image.Clone());
```

instead of

```
writer.AddFrame(image);
```

Hope it helps.